# Hadoop Balancer parameters doubts

Tags: hdfs, load-balancing

Can anyone elaborately explain the usage of this command?

```
hdfs balancer  [-source [-f <hosts-file> | <comma-separated list of hosts>]]
```

Issue in my cluster is that one of my datanode is utilising 93% of block pools of its capacity and the rest are using <80%.

Comment: It's to choose the source of the loadbalancer requests, in your case if you want to redirect the data from Node1 (the used one) you should put this one (and only this one) as source.

Comment: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/admin_hdfs_balancer.html       use this

Answer (score 0):

From HortonWorks documentation :

The new -source option allows specifying a source datanode list so that the Balancer selects blocks to move from only those datanodes. When the list is empty, all the datanodes can be chosen as a source. The default value is an empty list.

The option can be used to free up the space of some particular datanodes in the cluster. Without the -source option, the Balancer can be inefficient in some cases. Below is an example.

```
Datanodes (with the same capacity)  Utilization     Rack
D1  95%     A
D2  30%     B
D3, D4, D5  0%  B
```

In the table above, the average utilization is 25% so that D2 is within the 10% threshold. It is unnecessary to move any blocks from or to D2. Without specifying the source nodes, Balancer first moves blocks from D2 to D3, D4 and D5, since they are under the same rack, and then moves blocks from D1 to D3, D4 and D5. By specifying D1 as the source node, Balancer directly moves blocks from D1 to D3, D4 and D5.

This is the second article of the HDFS Balancer serious. We will explain the algorithm deployed by the Balancer for balancing the cluster in the next article.

Comment: While using the following command : "hdfs balancer -source CDCUEXDB05" getting below error :17/11/30 19:30:23 ERROR balancer.Balancer: Exiting balancer due an exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: args = [-source, CDCUEXDB05]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer$Cli.parse(Balancer.java:1600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer$Cli.run(Balancer.java:1556)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.balancer.Balancer.main(Balancer.java:1628)